# requests.patch returns 200 but nothing got updated

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests, patch

Im trying to do patch and update this clickthru column via api.

requests.patch('http://domain/api/orders/5894', {'clickthru': 'test.com'}, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'xxxxxxxxxx'})

It returns 200 but nothing's changed actually. I tried with postman, same headers and url, working fine. Does anyone know whats going on here? really appreciate any answers or thoughts.

Comment: requests does not use the same headers as postman. You may have a different User-Agent in Requests than Postman and the website might be filtering based on that. Alternatively maybe the site expects JSON not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content. In short, there are too few details here to actually help you.

Comment: I put application/json to headers, not working. And requests.get with that headers worked tho...